# Laravel simple router controller@action get NotFoundHttpException Error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

i'm below code is my simple route to use Controller action:

```
Route::get('/CheckCustomerTransactionPayment', 'PaymentTransactionController@check');
```

and this is my controller class:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\CustomerTransactions;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Payment\Payment;

class PaymentTransactionController extends Controller
{
    public function check(Request $request)
    {
        dd($request->all());
    }
}
```

i get this error:

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
```

URL to check that:

```
http://localhost/project/public/CheckCustomerTransactionPayment/112323
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have route defined like this:

```
Route::get('/CheckCustomerTransactionPayment', 'PaymentTransactionController@check');
```

you should call url

```
http://localhost/project/CheckCustomerTransactionPayment/
```

and if you want to pass id of payment in URL, you need to define your route like this:

```
Route::get('/CheckCustomerTransactionPayment/{id}', 'PaymentTransactionController@check');
```